# Finding Maximum Value in CSV File

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, max, import-from-csv

Have an assignment of finding average and maximum rainfall in file "[BoulderWeatherData.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8trlcnj8kwwydu/BoulderWeatherData.csv)". Have found the average using this code:

```
    rain = open("BoulderWeatherData.csv", "r")
    data = rain.readline()
    print(rain)
    data = rain.readlines()
    total = 0
    linecounter = 0
    for rain in data:
        linecounter = linecounter + 1
        print("The number of lines is", linecounter)

    for line in data:
        r = line.split(",")
        total = total + float(r[4])
    print(total)


    average = float(total / linecounter)
    print("The average rainfall is ", "%.2f" % average)
```

However, can't seem to find maximum using this same process. Attempted using *max*, function but the answer that must be obtained is float number, which can not be iterated through *max*.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give access to BoulderWeatherData.csv? The dropbox link appears to be dead.

Comment: My apologies. Re-upped the dropbox link. Hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: @user3308130 - Instead, please paste the relevant contents of your csv. Linking to outside code or files should not be done, as (like we just saw) it can be prone to deadlinks or other issues. SO questions should be self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv

INPUT  = "BoulderWeatherData.csv"
PRECIP = 4   # 5th column

with open(INPUT, "rU") as inf:
    incsv  = csv.reader(inf)
    header = next(incsv, None)    # skip header row
    precip = [float(row[PRECIP]) for row in incsv]

avg_precip = sum(precip, 0.) / (1 and len(precip))  # prevent div-by-0
max_precip = max(precip)

print(
    "Avg precip: {:0.3f} in/day, max precip: {:0.3f} in/day"
    .format(avg_precip, max_precip)
)
```

returns

```
Avg precip: 0.055 in/day, max precip: 1.980 in/day
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my prefered way of handling this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

rain = open("BoulderWeatherData.csv","r")

average = 0.0
total = 0
maxt = 0.0

for line in rain:
    try:
        p = float(line.split(",")[4])
        average += p
        total += 1
        maxt = max(maxt,p)
    except:
        pass

average = average / float(total)

print("Average:",average)
print("Maximum:",maxt)
```

This will output:

```
Average: 0.05465272591486193
Maximum: 1.98
```

Answer (score 0):

```
max=0 
for line in data:
      r = line.split(",")
      if float(r[4]) > max:
           max=float(r[4])
print(max)
```

something like that

Answer (score 0):

You're already accumulating `total` across loop iterations.

To keep track of a `maxvalue`, it's basically the same thing, except instead of adding you're `max`ing:

```
total = 0
maxvalue = 0

for line in data:
    r = line.split(",")
    value = float(r[4])
    total = total + value
    maxvalue = max(maxvalue, value)

print(total)
print(maxvalue)
```

Or, if you don't want to use the `max` function:

```
for line in data:
    r = line.split(",")
    value = float(r[4])
    total = total + value
    if value > maxvalue:
        maxvalue = value
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will attempt to find the maximum value, and the average value, of floats stored in the 5th position in a .csv.

```
rainval = []
```

Initializes the empty array where we will store values.

```
with open ("BoulderWeatherData.csv", "r") as rain:
```

Opens the .csv file and names it "rain".

```
    for lines in rain:
```

This reads every line in rain until the end of the file.

```
        rainval += [float(lines.strip().split(",")[4])]
```

We append the float value found in the fifth position (fourth index) of the line.

We repeat the above for every line located in the .csv file.

```
print (sorted(rainval)[len(rainval)])
```

This sorts the values in the rainval array and then takes the last (greatest) value, and prints it. This is the maximum value and is better than max because it can handle floats and not just ints.

```
print (sum(rainval)/len(rainval))
```

This prints the average rainfall.

---

Alternatively, if we don't want to use arrays:

```
maxrain = -float("inf")
total, count = 0, 0
with open ("test.txt", "r") as rain:
    for lines in rain:
        temp = float(lines.strip().split(",")[4])
        if maxrain < temp:
            maxrain = temp
        total += temp
        count += 1

print (maxrain)
print (total/count)
```

Comment: `data[]` isn't valid Python. `sorted(rain)` just returns a new sorted list, without modifying `rain` in any way. `rain[len(rain)]` is guaranteed to be an `IndexError`. You're also missing a colon. You're also using `rain`, the file object, in place of `data`. Even if you fixed all of that, your algorithm makes no sense—he needs to sort by the 4th element in each row, but you're trying to sort by the whole list of elements. And then you try to sum those lists as if they were numbers.

Comment: Well, you've replaced his `float` with an `int`. Also, unlike the original program, this one now has to store all of the data (of which there could be a _lot_) in a list. Why are you trying to rewrite his entire program in the first place, instead of just answering the part he asked for?

Comment: Can you add more background to your answer? Straight up code without a reason are not generally good answers.

Comment: Thank you Rico, is that better? I didn't consider that possibility abarnert, I prefer using arrays, but I guess you could go without using them. I'll update my answer now.