# Trying to open an external text file to be read in my main file

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

My code start to finish:

```
fo = open(BoulderWeatherData.csv, "r")
days=0
precip=0
lines = fo.readline()
listofpercip = []

for lines in fo:
    days = days +1
    splitting = line.split(",")
    precip = precip + float(splitting[4])
    listofpercip.append(spliting[4])
avg = round(listpercip / days, 2)

print ("the average rainfall is ", average)
print ("the max amount of rain for one day is:", max(listofpercip))

fname.close()
```

---

Terminal response:

```
    user@cu-cs-vm:~/Dropbox$ python3 recitation4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recitation4.py", line 5, in <module>
    fo = open(BoulderWeatherData.csv, "r")
NameError: name 'BoulderWeatherData' is not defined
```

I want to know what is wrong with the file im calling, it is called exactly and is found in the same directory as my main file.... I don't understand why it needs to be defined when all im doing is calling it....

Comment: I figured it out myself, I made an easy mistake... didn't "" my file name..... WOWW

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting your filename, as it is a String...

```
fo = open("BoulderWeatherData.csv", "r")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fo = open("BoulderWeatherData.csv","r")
```

i hope `" "` are missing,because it is a string

more information

[Finding Maximum Value in CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767529/finding-maximum-value-in-csv-file-python-3)