# how to extract the min value and max value from csv file using python

Tags: python, list, csv, max, min

i have a python script that read from csv file and append the requested columns into 2 empty list. after that i need to extract the minimum and maximum  value of the columns extracted.

[image]

i wrote this code but it seems not working be cause the result is empty .

## code:

```
import csv
mydelimeter = csv.excel()
mydelimeter.delimiter=";"
myfile = open("C:/Users/test/Documents/R_projects/homework/rdu-weather-history.csv")
myfile.readline()
myreader=csv.reader(myfile,mydelimeter)
mywind,mydate=[],[]
minTemp, maxTemp = [],[]

for row in myreader:
    print(row[1],row[2])
    minTemp.append(row[1])
    maxTemp.append(row[2])
print ("min value element : ", min(minTemp))
print ("max value element : ", min(maxTemp))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767529/finding-maximum-value-in-csv-file check this one

Comment: Looks like you have a typo print ("max value element : ", min(maxTemp)) should be print ("max value element : ", max(maxTemp))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Maximum Value in CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767529/finding-maximum-value-in-csv-file)

Answer (score 16):

You can Use Pandas Where You can load the data into DataFrames and They have inbuilt functions such as Sum,Max,Min,AVG etc.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('Name.csv')


#FINDING MAX AND MIN
p=df['ColumnName'].max()
q=df['ColumnName'].min()


print(q)
```

Thats it You will find the Min value in the Specified column.

Comment: You can also do `q = df["ColumnName"].describe()` which gives you a little more info too.

Answer (score 2):

This might help

```
import csv

with open('C:/Users/test/Documents/R_projects/homework/rdu-weather-history.csv', "r") as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    minVal, maxVal = [], []
    for i in data:
        minVal.append(i[1])
        maxVal.append(i[2])

print min(minVal)
print max(maxVal)
```

Comment: i tried your answer but it display this error 
File "C:\Users\test\Documents\Python_Projects\readCSV.py", line 14, in <module>
  minTemp.append(float(row[1]))

builtins.ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: You can them remove the float method.

Answer (score 1):

*Just in case you want the max and min values in the entire CSV file. This is applicable to even large datasets. Assume that your file is saved as file.csv*

```
    import pandas as pd 
    dff=pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

`Since you do not want to involve the dates`

```
    keep_col= ['temperaturemin','temperaturemax']
```

`I am using your csv but named it file`

```
    df=dff[keep_col]
```

`To find specific MAX AND MIN for each column`

```
    a=df['temperaturemin'].max()
    b=df['temperaturemax'].min()
    print(a,"\n",b)
```

`To find MAX AND MIN for the entire file.csv across all columns`

```
    print("Min:",df.min().min(),"Max:",df.max().max())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy library to find min value and max value.

```
import numpy as np

my_data = np.genfromtxt("C:/Users/test/Documents/R_projects/homework/rdu-weather-history.csv", delimiter=",", skip_header=True)
print ("min value element : ", my_data.min(axis=0)[1])
print ("max value element : ", my_data.max(axis=0)[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution for my question. 
it seems that the csv file  was containing an empty row 
what i did is  i  handle the exception in my code  so the code becomes:

```
import csv

mydelimeter = csv.excel()
mydelimeter.delimiter=";"
myfile = open("C:/Users/test/Documents/R_projects/homework/rdu-weather-history.csv")
myfile.readline()
myreader=csv.reader(myfile,mydelimeter)
mywind,mydate=[],[]
minTemp, maxTemp = [],[]

for row in myreader:
  #  print(row[1],row[2])
    try:
        minTemp.append(float(row[1]))
        maxTemp.append(float(row[2]))
    except ValueError:
        print ("error","on line",row)   

print ("min value element : ", min(minTemp))
print ("max value element : ", max(maxTemp))
```