# How to read csv, get max of column in python?

Tags: python

I have a csv file like below

```
Id  name    last    balance  acc type
1    tom     smith  2000     saving
2   terry   smith   1000     checking
3   mike    William 2000    saving
```

Want to get max of balance with names. Here I have 2 people having 2000 as balance.

Comment: Have you considered using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html)?

Comment: Please do a minimum of research before posting a question. This has been asked and answered a million times already.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920014/how-to-extract-the-min-value-and-max-value-from-csv-file-using-python/48920108

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to extract the min value and max value from csv file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920014/how-to-extract-the-min-value-and-max-value-from-csv-file-using-python)

Comment: What is the expected output for your sample? One name, two names, the whole line with maximum, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(PATH/from your computer)
df[df['balance'] == df['balance'].max()]['name','balance']
```

If you are using anaconda distribution then you can do this easily. Otherwise you require to download pandas package. Just type `sudo pip install pandas`, and it must do your work.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal:

```
pip install pandas
```

Then:

```
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
maxbalance = data[data['balance']==data['balance'].max()]['name','balance']
```

Where filename is the name of your csv file.

Answer (score 0):

`csv` module is included with python itself.

> The csv module’s reader and writer objects read and write sequences.
> Programmers can also read and write data in dictionary form using the
> DictReader and DictWriter classes.

source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

You can also install `pandas`, for example by running

```
pip install pandas
```

then you can use it to read CSV files with `read_csv()`

source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Python 3.0 (r30:67507, Dec  3 2008, 19:44:23) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pip install pandas
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pandas
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Anu/Desktop/python/projectfiles/data1.csv)
df[df['balance'] == df['balance'].max()]['name','balance']

Comment: getting error                                                                                                                                                     runfile('C:/Users/Anu/Desktop/python/project code/pandas.py', wdir='C:/Users/Anu/Desktop/python/project code')
  File "C:\Users\Anu\Desktop\python\project code\pandas.py", line 2
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Anu/Desktop/python/projectfiles/data1.csv)
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Anu/Desktop/python/projectfiles/data1.csv)` is wrong. Missing a quote at the end

Comment: import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Anu/Desktop/python/projectfiles/data1.csv')
df[df['balance'] == df['balance'].max()]['name','balance']- corrected the missing quote, but still getting same error. Will post error here

Comment: KeyError: ('name', 'balance')


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Anu\Desktop\python\project code\pandas.py", line 3, in <module>
    df[df['balance'] == df['balance'].max()]['name','balance']

  File "C:\Users\Anu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\Anu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: ('name', 'balance')