# python show values with 0 values and min max with name of product txt.file

Tags: python, txt

I've written code to find materials with min, max and 0 values, it finds min and mav values only, but i also need to show name of min and max values. And also I need to show 0 values. I have **material.txt** where i have name of `material, quantity, price, company` that sales this material:

```
Cement,123,10000,some company
Metall,122,11000,some another company
```

here is the code:

```
def how_many_materials():
    print("Material with min val:")
    with open('material.txt', "r", encoding="UTF8") as csvfile:
        data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

        minval = []
        maxval = []
        for i in data:
            minval.append(i[1])
            maxval.append(i[1])

    print(min(minval))

    print("Material with max val:")
    print(max(maxval))
    print("Materials with 0 quantity:")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920014/how-to-extract-the-min-value-and-max-value-from-csv-file-using-python

Answer (score 0):

We just need to add the material name also:

```
import csv
def how_many_materials():
    with open('material.txt', "r", encoding="UTF8") as csvfile:
        data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

        minval = []
        maxval = []
        zeroquantity = []
        for i in data:
            minval.append((i[0],i[2]))
            maxval.append((i[0],i[2]))
            if i[1]==0:
                zeroquantity.append(i[0])
        
    print("Material with min val: {0} - {1}".format(min(minval,key=lambda x:x[1])[0],min(minval,key=lambda x:x[1])[1]))
    print("Material with max val: {0} - {1}".format(max(maxval,key=lambda x:x[1])[0],max(maxval,key=lambda x:x[1])[1]))
    print("Materials with 0 quantity: ",len(zeroquantity))
    for i in zeroquantity:
        print(i)

how_many_materials()
```

sample output would be:

```
Material with min val: Cement - 10000
Material with max val: Metall - 11000
Materials with 0 quantity:  0
```

Comment: everything works fine,except with 0 quantity...

Comment: it shows Materials with 0 quantity: 0 even if it exist 3 values with 0

Comment: Did the rows with 0 quantity have same no of values like other rows? If you give a row with 0 quantity for example it would be helpful.